# What is difference between @tailwind and @import, what special does @tailwind do?

Tags: reactjs, import, tailwind-css

I want to create a `tailwind` based components library for `react-js`,

What special does `@tailwind` do?

How is it different from `@import`?

I want to add custom component's css with `@apply`

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

 /* this is a custom tailwind based @layer component for button */
@import "./atoms/buttons/buttons.tailwind.css";
```